# Event sender from custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, events, custom-controls

I have a control which extends `UserControl`. This control contains two ComboBox controls. I've created an event handler which fires when either of the combos changes:

```
public event EventHandler ComboChanged
{
add { cmbA.SelectedIndexChanged += value; cmbB.SelectedIndexChanged += value; }
remove {...}
}
```

When I add an event handler to this event, is there any way for the `sender` to be reported as the custom control (i.e. the ComboBox's parent control) rather than the ComboBox itself? Or am I trying to do something I shouldn't be doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have something like this :

```
public event EventHandler MyControlChanged
```

and then in your userControl two functions for each of the ComboBox

```
protected void oncmbA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (MyControlChanged!=null)
     MyControlChanged(this, e);//or some new Eventagrs that you wish to communicate
}

protected void oncmbB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (MyControlChanged!=null)
     MyControlChanged(this, e);//or some new Eventagrs that you wish to communicate
}
```

this would then refer to the UserControl and not to the combobox that fired your UserControl's event.

Answer (score 3):

Yoann's answer is the way to go. Here's a similar pattern, but with some minor differences.

```
// Default listener makes null-check unnecessary when raising event.
// Note that no custom implementations are provided for add, remove.
public event EventHandler ComboChanged = delegate { };

...

foreach(var comboxBox in new[] {cmbA, cmbA})
{
  // Attach listener to combo-box's event that raises our own event.
  // Lambda-expression is ok since we don't intend to ever unsubscribe.
  comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => ComboChanged(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Yours is more elegant however ;)

Comment: Thanks, always useful to have an alternative.